# Getting error "library not found ldoubleconversion" in XCode 12.5 for ReactNative project

Tags: xcode, react-native, build, compiler-errors

Getting Error:
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Env:
XCode: 12.5
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.4

Note:

1. Already using Xcodeworkspace
2. Tried performing pod deintegrate && pod install

Comment: same issue. Did you find a solution?